# Nginx not able to run css and js

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

My nginx server is not able to run js and css.When I try to navigate manually to css/js it gets downloaded.Here is my vhost.conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sample.domain.tld;
        root /home/domain.tld/www/;
        index index.php;
         location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;

        }


}
```

here is my nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: Not sure if troll or... - if you create a index.php or index.html and create a link to the js or css does that work? What are you expecting to see, the raw output of the .css or .js file?

Comment: Nginx does not run anything.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try to navigate manually to css/js it gets downloaded.

Right, and that's **precisely** what is supposed to happen.

CSS and javascript files are interpreted by the **browser**. All your server needs to be concerned with is getting the file to the browser, which it is doing.

Comment: but it's not able to run ? I don't see any js or css running on website

Comment: If css and javascript are not working correctly in this instance, it has nothing to do with the server, but rather how those files are being included in or referenced from your html.

Comment: They were working pretty much fine before suddenly it broke . I am suspecting it's treating css and jss as octet-stream?